# Iterate through second columns in a table in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have table in the dom that looks like this

```
<div id="table">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>c</td>
  <td>d</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>c</td>
  <td>d</td>
</tr> 
</div>
```

I want to iterate through this table, such as `$('#table').each(function(){})` but I only want to iterate through the second column.  So the ones which in this example have a value of b.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like this has been asked and answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917143/loop-through-the-cells-of-a-columns-not-cells-of-a-rows-with-jquery-or-js-on

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {

});
```

Comment: This also matches any nested tables inside the main table...so some `td` elements could be matched several times. Also, you don't need the `tr` part, as `td` is always a child of `tr`. And it's more readable and easier for jQuery when you use stuff like `.find` or `.children` instead of a big selector string for jQuery to parse

Answer (score 12):

Using the `nth-child` selector in jQuery, this should work:

```
$("#table").find("td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {

});
```

This uses the `nth-child` selector, http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ , which as the link states, would select all `<td>` elements that are the 2nd child of their parent (which would be a `<tr>`).

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/GshRz/

If you are looking for a selector that gets the `<td>`s that are only immediately in the table (like not in a nested table), then use something like:

```
$("#table").children("tbody").children("tr").children("td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GshRz/1/

Depending on your structure (where you might include a `<thead>`), you could use `.children("thead, tbody")` instead of just `.children("tbody")`.

Also, in case you want to be grabbing several columns, it could be easier to select the `<tr>` elements and then get their children `<td>` elements. For example:

```
$("#table1").children("tbody").children("tr").each(function (i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var my_td = $this.children("td");
    var second_col = my_td.eq(1);
    var third_col = my_td.eq(2);
    console.log("Second Column Value (row " + i + "): " + second_col.html());
    console.log("Third Column Value (row " + i + "): " + third_col.html());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GshRz/2/

What selectors you use and where, is up to the structure and content of your table. So remember to differentiate between `children` and `find`, and `nth-child` and `eq`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, I went ahead and selected @namkha87, because it works and it seems to be faster than doing a find()

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#table td:nth-child(2)").each(function (index) {
   alert('Row no. ' + (index+1) + ', Column 2 : ' + $(this).html());
});
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7L4F/1/)