# Filter table with multiple selects using jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, filter

I have a table with multiple columns, I want to filter it using multiple selects. Each select corresponds to a specific column. When a select change, the table will show only rows where the column correspondent to the select has the same value.

I´ve started a little JSFiddle. Any idea will help.

What I´ve done so far:

```
var filter = $('select');

filter.change(function() {
    var table = $('table');
    var rows = $('tr');
    var filterValue = $(this).val();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ibnclaudius/BnPa6/15/

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you're trying to highlight the td's which is equal to the options selected.

```
var filter = $('select');
filter.change(function () {
    var table = $('table');
    var rows = $('tr');
    var filterValue = $(this).val();
    $('tr td').css('color', 'black')
    $('tr td').each(function () {
        if (filterValue == $(this).text()) {  // I have testing for the matches
            $(this).css('color', 'red')
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the key point that you have to know is *iterating the `td`s* using **`.each()`**

Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BnPa6/17/)

Hope you understand.

### Updates:

1) Get the label name of the select being clicked

```
var col = $(this).parent().find('label').text();
```

2) Here I'm getting the column number using the below line

```
var colNumber = col.replace("Column ", "")
```

This returns the column number, of the select that is being selected.

3) With the help of this [**`answer`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14493457/1671639), I found a way to iterate the columns.

Now you understand more depth.

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(" + colNumber + ")").each(function () {
        if (filterValue == $(this).text()) {
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
```

### [JSFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/BnPa6/18/)

For you 1st comments, just trigger the **`change`** event like below

```
$('select').change();
```

### [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/BnPa6/20/)

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot. Just one more thing, all filters should work together. For example, you change the filter for columns 1 and 2, so only rows where both filters are ok will be shown. Any idea how I can manage this?

Comment: Another thing, each filter corresponds to a specific column, so filtering column 1 should not filter column 2 the same thing.

Comment: @ClaudiusIbn This seems to me more interesting ;)

Comment: @ClaudiusIbn I have updated my answer, go through it.  I loved to answer it.

Comment: Thank you again. There is no way to answer without loving it. :) Almost there, but I think I did not explain right as the filter should work. Only the row where all collumns match all filters should be colored.

Comment: By the way, any tip you can give to improve my code I'll be graceful!

Comment: The links do not work. Can you update it with snippets? I accidentally downvoted the answer by the way. I can only change it if you change the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

The jsfiddle links do not work. A snippet would help.

If you want to use a filter for every td available in your rows, you can use this script:

```js
(function(document) {
 'use strict';

 var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

  var _input;

  function _onInputEvent(e) {
   _input = e.target;
   var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
   Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
    Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
     Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
    });
   });
  }

  function _filter(row) {
   var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
   row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
  }

  return {
   init: function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
    Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
     input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
    });
   }
  };
 })(Array.prototype);

 document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
   LightTableFilter.init();
  }
 });

})(document);
```

```html
<section class="container">

 <input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Filter">

 <table class="order-table table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Number 2</th>
    <th>Number 2</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Column One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>352353</td>
    <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Column Two</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>4646</td>
    <td>2</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

</section>
```