# How to make table that returns average grade of students with button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have been trying to make a table with names and grades of people, while using a button that when clicked it will calculate the average of all the grades that were put inside the table until then.

first I tried just to sum it but with no sucess.

```
$("button").click(function ()
```

My codepen is [here](http://codepen.io/ronilitman/pen/qdEvXo)

Comment: looks like your sum += i is adding your index over and over, is that what you wanted?

Comment: I want that when I click on "calculate average" it will calculate all the average grades, I just don't know how to continue from this point.

Comment: Your code should be in the question so it is a standalone problem. We shouldn't have to go to an external site to see your basic code. Links rot and when future users have similar issues it is much simpler when the code is here to compare to. The external site should only be used as secondary for demo

Comment: Also, you might find your answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493423/iterate-through-second-columns-in-a-table-in-jquery

Comment: Got it. Sorry, I'm new to this site. Thank you!

Comment: please remember to accept @bytesized's answer if it worked for you. He'll gain reputation for taking the time to help you and you'll acquire 2 points for accepting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this javascript

```
$("button").click(function () {

  var sum = 0;
  var quantity = 0;

  $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
    sum += parseInt($(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text() , 10);
    quantity++;
  });
  $("tfoot tr:last-child td:last-child").text(sum/quantity);

});
```